# How to add new or existing multi-select tags when creating a page in Notion API?

Tags: api, notion-api, notion

I can't figure out how to add multi-select tags when creating a page in Notion API. Single select tags are extremely easy to add:

```
"City": {
    "select": {
        "name": "New York",
    }
}
```

But my attempts to add multi-select tags end up failing.

```
"City": {
    "multi_select": {
           "options": [
            {
              "name": "New York", 
              "color": "red"
            },
            {
              "name": "Tbilisi",
              "color": "gray"
            }
          ]},

}
```

Here's the error I get

```
{"object":"error","status":400,"code":"validation_error","message":"body failed validation. Fix one:\nbody.properties.City.title should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.rich_text should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.url should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.multi_select should be an array, instead was `{\"options\":[{\"name\":\"apple\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"name\":\"Ora...`.\nbody.properties.City.people should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.email should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.phone_number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.relation should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.files should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.City.status should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Name.id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Name.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Name.start should be defined, instead was `undefined`."}
```

Do you have a working example of how it should be done?

Here's the full payload

```
newPageData = {
    "parent": { "database_id": 'some id' },
    "properties": {
        "Name": {
            "title": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "New page"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
         "City": {
            "multi_select": {
                "options": [
                    {
                    "name": "New York", 
                    "color": "red"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "Tbilisi",
                    "color": "gray"
                    }
                ]},

    },
        "Date": {
                "date": {
                    "start": "2023-02-06",
                    "end": None,
                }
            },
        "Link": {
                "url": "example.info"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When populating / updating a Multi-Select property, you don't need to include `"options"` or specify the option's colour so this should work -

```
"City": {
    "multi_select": [
        {
            "name": "New York"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tbilisi"
        }
    ]
}
```

you should remove the first comma at the end of your list of options for the City property too -

```
    ]},

},
```